# Cannot capture annotations in a PDImageXObject using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am highlighting (in green) certain words on each page of my input pdf document using PDAnnotationTextMarkup. A sample screenshot is seen below;

[image: Page section with annotation]

However, when I crop this part of the page and try to save it as a PDImageXObject, I get the following result;

[image: Page section without annotation]

The code I am using to crop the image is as follows;

```
public PDImageXObject cropAndSaveImage(int pageNumber, Rectangle dimensions) 
{
  PDImageXObject pdImage = null;

  // Extract arguments from the rectangle object
  float x = dimensions.getXValue();
  float y = dimensions.getYValue();
  float w = dimensions.getWidth();
  float h = dimensions.getHeight();

  PDRectangle pdRectangle;
  int pageResolution = 140;

  try{          
      // Fetch the source page
      PDPage sourcePage = document.getPage(pageNumber-1);

      // Calculate height of the source page
      PDRectangle mediaBox = sourcePage.getMediaBox();
      float sourcePageHeight = mediaBox.getHeight();

      // Fetch the original crop box of the page
      PDRectangle originalCrop = sourcePage.getCropBox();

      /*
       * PDF Crop Box - Here we initialize the rectangle area 
       * that is needed to crop a region from the PDF document
      */
       if(pageOriginShifted)
       {
          pdRectangle = new PDRectangle(x, sourcePageHeight - y, w, h);
       }
       else
       {
          pdRectangle = new PDRectangle(x, y, w, h);
       }

       // Crop the required rectangle from the source page
       sourcePage.setCropBox(pdRectangle);

       // PDF renderer
       PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

    // Convert to an image
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = renderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageNumber-1, pageResolution, ImageType.RGB);
    pdImage = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bufferedImage);

    // Restore the original page back to the document
    sourcePage.setCropBox(originalCrop);

    return pdImage;
  }catch(Exception e)
   {
     Logger.logWithoutTimeStamp(LOG_TAG + "cropAndSaveImage()", Logger.ERROR, e);
   }
    return null;
}
```

I am quite perplexed on why the highlighted text in green won't show up. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated (I cannot attach the input PDF document owing to privacy issues).

Thanks in advance,
Bharat.

Comment: I have to admit that I do not really understand the issue. Can you share a sample PDF and code and explain what in contrast to the output of your code you expected?

Comment: @mkl I have rephrased my question and attached a couple of snapshots and code to better highlight the issue. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Ah, ok. Simply said, PDFBox' `PageDrawer.drawPage` (which eventually is called by your `renderer.renderImageWithDPI`) and in particular `PageDrawer.showAnnotation` called by it only knows how to render annotations that bring along their own appearance streams and a very few without, text markup not among them. This might be your problem.

Comment: @mkl: Many thanks for the note. I did follow the example of 'CustomPageDrawer' and experiment with creating an appearance stream which did not work but your point that text markup may not be supported makes sense now. Guess I'll try with other annotations instead of text...